# PyQt5 красивый текст, наклонный или жирный

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Как сделать в наклонный текст или жирный в QMenuBar или QLabel?

Comment: Кст, а под `Bar` вы какой виджет имели ввиду? `QStatusBar`? `QProgressBar`?

Comment: @gil9red menuBar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Вариант 1 – HTML

Используйте в тексте теги HTML такие как `<i>` – для наклонного текста и `<b>` – для жирного.

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/d25be6f5422724b00359e6e10a4a6ae813a56aab/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/QLabel_bold_italic_text/use__html.py):

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

app = QApplication([])

label_1 = QLabel()
label_1.setText('<i>Hello</i> <b>World</b><i><b>!!!</b><i>')

label_2 = QLabel()
label_2.setText('nothing...')

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(label_1)
layout.addWidget(label_2)

mw = QWidget()
mw.setLayout(layout)
mw.show()

app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

## Вариант 2 – QSS

Еще можно через [Qt Style Sheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) (QSS) настроить шрифт для конкретного виджета, [например](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/301d344e7993503d28462a186de29d4c3a123e83/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/QLabel_bold_italic_text/use__qss__qt_style_sheet__local.py):

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

app = QApplication([])

label_1 = QLabel()
label_1.setText('Hello World!!!')
label_1.setStyleSheet("""
    font: bold italic;
    color: green;
    background-color: black;
""")

label_2 = QLabel()
label_2.setText('nothing...')

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(label_1)
layout.addWidget(label_2)

mw = QWidget()
mw.setLayout(layout)
mw.show()

app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

А это уже настройка для всего приложения для всех `QLabel`'ов, [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/301d344e7993503d28462a186de29d4c3a123e83/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/QLabel_bold_italic_text/use__qss__qt_style_sheet__global.py):

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

app = QApplication([])
app.setStyleSheet('QLabel { font: bold italic }')

label_1 = QLabel()
label_1.setText('Hello World!!!')

label_2 = QLabel()
label_2.setText('nothing...')

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(label_1)
layout.addWidget(label_2)

mw = QWidget()
mw.setLayout(layout)
mw.show()

app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[А вот тут для конкретного виджета](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/ff14d8b80c186b77215485aba99bb5935d6190f5/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/QLabel_bold_italic_text/use__qss__qt_style_sheet__by_object_name.py) по его *object name*:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

app = QApplication([])
app.setStyleSheet('''
#welcome { font: bold italic }
#label_foo_bar { 
    font: italic;
    color: green;
}
''')

label_1 = QLabel()
label_1.setObjectName('welcome')
label_1.setText('Hello World!!!')

label_2 = QLabel()
label_2.setText('nothing...')

label_3 = QLabel()
label_3.setObjectName('label_foo_bar')
label_3.setText('FooBar')

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(label_1)
layout.addWidget(label_2)
layout.addWidget(label_3)

mw = QWidget()
mw.setLayout(layout)
mw.show()

app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

## Вариант 3 – QFont

Кроме `QSS` настроить отображение можно используя класс [QFont](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfont.html), [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/301d344e7993503d28462a186de29d4c3a123e83/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/QLabel_bold_italic_text/use__QFont.py):

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

app = QApplication([])

label_1 = QLabel()
label_1.setText('Hello World!!!')

font = label_1.font()
font.setItalic(True)
font.setBold(True)
label_1.setFont(font)

label_2 = QLabel()
label_2.setText('nothing...')

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(label_1)
layout.addWidget(label_2)

mw = QWidget()
mw.setLayout(layout)
mw.show()

app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Также приведу пример для `QMenuBar` (при желании, через QSS это тоже реализуется):

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QMainWindow

app = QApplication([])

mw = QMainWindow()
menu_file = mw.menuBar().addMenu('File')
menu_about = mw.menuBar().addMenu('About')

font = mw.menuBar().font()
font.setItalic(True)
font.setBold(True)
mw.menuBar().setFont(font)

menu_file.addAction('Open')
menu_file.addAction('New')
menu_file.addAction('Quit')

mw.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну или через `qss` чтобы постоянный был курсивный или жирный =)

Comment: @Twiss, ага, добавил :)